# Example of using `thebibliography` in the `CurVe` document class

Tags: bibliographies, cv, curve-class

I'm using the CurVe document class for C.V.s . I'd like an example of using `thebibliography` environment in this document class as I'm having trouble figuring it out from just the documentation. I want to have citations within my C.V., by the way, if this is possible.

Here is my minimal (non)working example:

fav_book.tex:

```
\begin{rubric}{My Favourite Book}

 This is my favourite book~\cite{fav}
\end{rubric}
```

biblography.tex:

```
\begin{rubric}{}
\begin{thebibliography}{}

 \bibitem{fav} Thor, A.U., 2017. \textit{Best book ever}. 1st ed. London: Best Publishers.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{rubric}
```

CV.tex:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{curve}
\begin{document}
\makerubric{fav_book}
\makerubric{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

This is the relevant part of the documentation:

> If you find this process too cumbersome, however, you can use the standard
>   LATEX bibliography mechanisms with CurVe: the thebibliography environment is
>   supported along with its \bibitem companion. The behavior is actually that of
>   a rubric environment with its \entry* companion (with an empty prefix however).
>   Hence, the layout of the bibliography remains consistent with the rest
>   of the cv. This fact has two implications however: firstly, the argument to the
>   thebibliography environment is unused in CurVe (but remains for compatibility
>   with the rest of LATEX) because CurVe itself formats the keys and contents properly
>   aligned. Secondly, the bibliographic environment must reside in its own file,
>   as any other rubric. Don’t forget that if you happen to write the environment
>   manually.

Comment: Please have a look at [Manually adding references](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References) and check if it just works. If not, please provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked it out: my mistake was to assume that the bibliography needed to be in a `rubric` like the others. Actually, bibliography.tex should look like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

 \bibitem{fav} Thor, A.U., 2017. \textit{Best book ever}. 1st ed. London: Best Publishers.


\end{thebibliography}
```

This should work together with the rest of the files in the example given in my question.